# XCode 4.5 not able to upload App to the iTunes App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.5

[image]

I upgraded my XCode 4.5 before 3 days and now whenever I am uploading any application to the app store I am getting three errors even though there is nothing wrong at my side. I have signed the app with the proper provisional profile under the correct certificate. But still I am getting the same issue regardless I upload any app from my XCode to the App store. Please help me if anyone can solve this issue.

Comment: On a side note: I like your app icon. =P

Comment: I have got the solution for this problem. Actually the problem is I made the project in old SDK and then I was working with the latest Xcode version 4.5 and there was some problem from the XCode internally may be some configuration issue from Apple. So, I was not able to submit the application to the App Store. But now I created the entire project into the new XCode and the issue is fixed now. I can submit the application to App Store successfully and not having any issue which I was facing before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and build a new archive? Maybe review the project configuration. It isn't unusual to break a project metadata after an upgrade (I got some headaches after changing from GCC to LLVM).

Answer (score 0):

It's the second warning I think you should be looking at first.

It looks as if you are building with either the wrong provisioning profile (you shouldn't be using Development or AdHoc) or you are building with an expired Distribution certificate.

Comment: Jep, I'd guess that as well. I also had something similar, thought that all profiles are right (because Xcode told me they are), but in fact only a complete reset of the certificates etc. resolved it on my side.